# Keep a remote repo up to date from GitHub to GitHub Enterprise

Tags: git, github

I've followed this guide https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.2/admin/articles/moving-a-repository-from-github-com-to-github-enterprise/

But now I am trying to figure out how to keep the Enterprise repo up-to-date after I have initially cloned it.

I've tried a few things, like git fetch origin, and then git push enterprise mirror, but it always says that "Everything up-to-date"

Not sure what to try next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its just dealing with two remotes. If you have your `enterprise` and `public` remotes set up correctly you can use this command (I have it aliased to `git sync`):

`!git checkout master && git pull --ff-only public master && git push enterprise master`

This will pull down public changes and push them to enterprise. Swap public and enterprise if you need to go the other way.

If that doesn't solve your problem, run `git remote -v` and make sure your remotes are set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this is bare repo, so when I run `git checkout master` I get `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brian for helping,

I was able to resolve it by using:

`git fetch origin`

`git push enterprise master`